# Import data into an Excel spreadsheet from SQL Server and another Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I'm trying to import data into an Excel spreadsheet from an existing Excel spreadsheet and SQL Server using SSIS.

The first source has UserID, Security_Profile, Warehouse

The second source has UserID, UserName, Job Title

I want the excel spreadsheet to show UserName, Job Title, UserID, SecurityProfile, and Warehouse on the same row.

I tried Adding two sources, then sorting them by UserID, then merging them and sending that data into an Excel spreadsheet. I ran it but the problem is that it puts the user name and job titles on different rows. I want the User Name and Job Title to be inserted on the same rows where the UserID is the same. I'm not sure what to do from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, I'd like every time I run this SSIS project I want it to overwrite the file, not add more rows. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. What the problem was I had to use a Merge Join instead of a Merge.